# Overhead when relocating a directory to a different file system using a symbolic link

Tags: linux, filesystems, symlink, performance

I need to relocate some frequently accessed files to a different file system. The simplest way of doing this is to move the directory containing the files to the new file system and creating a symbolic link from the old location.

ie. `/var/yaydata` is moved to `/mnt/data2/yaydata` and `ln -s /mnt/data2/yaydata /var/yaydata`

What I want to know is will there be any noticeable performance impact, assuming that files in yaydata will be opened and closed frequently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not really.

You can test the by debug tracing your operation. Assuming you're on linux, that's `strace`.

```
 mkdir test1
 ln -s test1 test2
 strace -o strace1.log ls -l test1
 strace -o strace2.log ls -l test2
```

Then diff your two logs.

You'll see they're basically the same sequence of operations. They call `lstat` which is a version of `stat` that follows symlinks.

You can test the speed difference by adding the `-T` flag to `strace`. With the symlink, the `lstat` took 0.000035s, and without it took 0.000031s.

Things like file metadata like this are also cached quite efficiently - most caches assume that metadata is a fairly high priority because it's frequent access and small.

So short answer - no, it's not likely to cause you any significant overhead.